# iPad physical keyboard Return key doesn't dismiss my UIAlertControllers correctly

Tags: swift, keyboard, uialertcontroller

I am working to give my app better support for the iPad physical keyboard. Everything is behaving pretty much as expected, except the keyboard's Return key is not dismissing UIAlertControllers that do not have a text field.

The alerts are displayed properly, and the OK buttons are highlighted to indicate that preferredAction is set properly. Both alerts respond properly to touch, but only the one with the text field responds to the physical keyboard's Return key.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620102-preferredaction) says "If the iOS device is connected to a physical keyboard, pressing the Return key triggers the preferred action.", but I'm not seeing that. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Testing with iPad Pro 11" (3rd generation), iOS 15.5, Apple Smart Folio keyboard, Xcode 13.4.1, Monterey 12.4

```
@IBAction func displayTextAlert(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // The physical keyboard's Return key properly dismisses this alert
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Text Alert", message: "This is an alert with a text field.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let textOKAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: { _ in
    NSLog("The text alert occurred.")
    })
    
    // this line is the only difference between the two
    alert.addTextField()
    
    alert.addAction(textOKAction)
    alert.preferredAction = textOKAction
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func displayAlert(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // The physical keyboard's Return key does not dismiss this alert

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: { _ in
    NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occurred.")
    })
    
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.preferredAction = okAction
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, this works fine in the Simulator (where the physical keyboard is your computer's keyboard).

Comment: Very interesting. Are you running iOS 14 on your simulator? I get the same (incorrect) behaviour if I use an iOS 15.5 simulator, but the correct behaviour on an iOS 14.5 simulator.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that what I tested with was, by chance, an _iPhone_ simulator (running iOS 15.5). I can confirm that an _iPad_ simulator running iOS 15.5 similarly doesn't respond to the computer hardware keyboard. Maybe there's some additional iPad requirement we don't know about?

Comment: I just tried a Magic Keyboard over Bluetooth with my iPad Pro (iOS 15.5), and it did not work as expected. Same keyboard with an iPhone (iOS 15.5) worked fine. Same keyboard with an iPad running iOS 14.6 revealed that iOS 14 and 15 handle displaying alerts differently, and that's a whole other thing... so anyway, this issue does appear to be specific to iOS 15 and iPad at this point.

Comment: Great research. Sorry I'm not actually _helping._ It feels like either it's a bug or there is some additional "switch" we are supposed to throw, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: It does feel like a bug at this point, so I've sent some feedback. Your comments have been helpful. More data is always good. Thank you!